# Pythoncard textarea how to set text

Tags: textarea, pythoncard

I have created a textarea in my python project using Pythoncard

The problem is, I don't know how to call it in my project to change the text. It's called myTextArea.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the TextArea doc here: http://pythoncard.sourceforge.net/framework/components/TextArea.html

I think the methods you want to use are appendText and writeText

Answer (score 0):

From within the PythonCard-generated GUI class:

```
self.components.myTextArea.clear() ## clear the TextArea
self.components.myTextArea.text = "initial text" ## directly set text
self.components.myTextArea.appendText("\nhello world") ## append text
self.components.myTextArea.writeText("\nhello world2") ## append text
```